# Is there anyway to bypass the Geo-IP restriction when trying to stream movies outside US?

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire

I have an Amazon Kindle fire, I have an Amazon Prime subscription, *and* I am living outside the US.

Every single time I want to enjoy Amazon streaming video service reserved for the Prime membership, the Amazon Geo-IP check stops me from doing so ("this service is unavailable in your region" ).

Any idea to bypass this Geo-IP check?

Comment: Apart from using Proxy, may be contacting customer support will help. I had downloaded Amazon Kindle in my phone and registered using US Address while I live in Nepal. After downloading 5 or so free books, amazon told me to contact customer support as my IP was not from US. They said if I was living outside US the support person might be able to help.

Comment: @roxan, from what I know, the Amazon support is more likely to ask you to prove that you are a US resident rather than to really help you solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, they wanted me to prove them that I was a US resident living outside due to some business.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17248/is-there-anyway-to-bypass-the-geo-ip-restriction-when-trying-to-stream-movies-ou

Comment: @TonyCuthbert , why are you linking the question to itself in the comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question. Yes it is possible, by using VPN or DNS service.

Comment: you should be aware, service like Netflix are already suspending service for people that use Proxy/VPN/DNS to bypass their geo-ip restrictions. They have these location based restrictions because of contracts with studios, and local laws.

Comment: And if this does work, you should provide a little information, like how you set something like that up on android, or something. Think about the next person that may have this question. Your answer may technically answer the initial question, but for most users, it will just create more questions.